# How can we copy the list of issues from one project to another in JIRA?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jira, jira-agile

We have one project in JIRA and we have uploaded all the issues under it. The issues are stored in the category wise structure.

> For Example: Module 1 >> Test Cases

We want to fetch(copy) the test cases of few categories into another project. Is there any mechanism available in JIRA to copy multiple test cases in one go?

Kindly suggest the best possible solution of the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options which may work for you:

1. You could try use the *Structure Plugin* for Jira:

   [Cloning Multiple Issues](https://wiki.almworks.com/display/structure/Cloning+Multiple+Issues)
2. Try a Marketplace plugin *Bulk Clone Basic* for Jira

   [Bulk Clone Basic Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.lbcg.jira.plugins.bulkclone.BulkClone/server/overview)
3. Another Try/Buy option *Clone Plus Plugin* for Jira

   [bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCPP](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JCPP/overview)
4. Alternatively you could *export* the issues you need, adjust and then *import* as a new project:

   [confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/import-and-export-data-873871368.html](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/import-and-export-data-873871368.html)

Comment: Thanks @Tom for your reply. Here is my exact requirement. As I mentioned above that we are looking for some repository kind of stuff in JIRA. We want to upload test cases on the basis of categories in one of the project and we want to import these test cases in another projects. For example: I have uploaded test cases under the category 'GUI' in master project and in another project/working projects, whenever tester selects 'GUI' category for testing then all the test cases from GUI category would come available for the tester to import. Is your suggested solution works for my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is *still* not supported in JIRA. The workaround mentioned in [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41698636/93394) uses the Export/Import functionality, but, apparently, this does not copy any attachments (at least, not with JiraServer), so it is an unsatisfactory solution.

Unfortunately, AddOns appear to be the only option. [Here's a list  that shows the currently supported cloning tools in the Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?query=clone). (At this writing, it looks like there are 3 or 4 options that promise to do the trick -- all "Try/Buy". I have not tested them.)

Answer (score 0):

For those who aren't concerned about attachments, here's the detailed steps for exporting and importing to copy issues from one Jira project to another (in 2022 anyway).

1. In the source project, navigate to the Issues tab
2. Click the Export Issues button
3. Click Export Excel CSV (all fields)
4. Save the file in the dialog that appears
5. (Optional) Edit the CSV if you like although you can change some things in the import process
6. Click the ... in the top right
7. Select Import issues from CSV
8. Click Choose File
9. Select the CSV exported earlier
10. Click Next
11. Set "Import to Project" to your destination project
12. Click Next
13. Set fields you wish to map (e.g. Assignee, Components, Description)
14. Click Next
15. Click Begin Import

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution for this

1. Search all the issue based on the filter.
2. Select all issue and top 3 dot select clone issue.
3. Follow the instruction and it moves all the issues.

Comment: This answer explains how to _move_ issues, but the OP wants to _copy_ (i.e., clone) them, while leaving the originals in place.